# Pandas' offset.yearend is returning next year

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have observed that, `pandas' offsets.YearEnd` is returning next year if input date is year end. Below is one such example

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime('2000-12-31') + pd.offsets.YearEnd() ## Timestamp('2001-12-31 00:00:00')
```

Is it expected behaviour? How can I force to have same year if actual date itself is year-end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly specify the offset as `0` which will make sure that the calendar year does not gets incremented, See the below example,

```
>>> pd.to_datetime('2000-12-31') + pd.offsets.YearEnd(0)
Timestamp('2000-12-31 00:00:00')

>>> pd.to_datetime('2000-06-02') + pd.offsets.YearEnd(0)
Timestamp('2000-12-31 00:00:00')
```